# Linq with ef core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

how can I use identity tables in asp.net core like AspNetUsers with Linq technique
for example

```
var x = (from a in db.table1 join b in AspNetUsers .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DbContext.Users to retire user information ,from  [`IdentityDbContext.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/d4d105d5b529c8e1701010cb49bc115f0aa23ed0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of Users.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of User claims.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of User logins.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of User roles.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of User tokens.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TUserToken> UserTokens { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of roles.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TRole> Roles { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{TEntity}"/> of role claims.
/// </summary>
public DbSet<TRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
```

Something like :

```
var categories = from c in db.categories
join u in db.Users
on c.myID equals u.Id
select new { ID=c.myID, name= u.UserName};
var result = categories.ToList();
```